# What is wrong with the validation of the form

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

For some reason validation of the form does not work - it allows empty field submitting, what's wrong?

```
TextFormField(
  validator: (val) {
    if (val.trim().length == 0) {
      return Lang.key(context, 'wrongDeviceName');
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  onSaved: (val) =>
      _name = toBeginningOfSentenceCase(val.trim()),
  initialValue:
      id == 0 ? '' : model.byId(id, tableName).name.toString(),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
),
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does any pattern work for you? What if you try `[A-Za-z0-9 ]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the question updated - the simpliest validation does not work ...

Comment: Ok, try it like this: `validator: validateDeviceName`, then add a function `String validateDeviceName(String value) {
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z0-9\s]*$');
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
      return 'Enter Valid Device Name';
    else
      return null;
  }`

Comment: as it terned out the reason was in localization data

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew anyway your comment was usefull it allowed  to reject unwanted symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may declare a `validateDeviceName` function in the `validator` and implement it:

```
validator: validateDeviceName
```

And then

```
String validateDeviceName(String value)
{
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z0-9\s]*$');
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
        return 'Enter Valid Device Name';
    else
        return null;
}
```

The `^[A-Za-z0-9\s]*$` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9\s]*` - 0 or more (`*`) characters that are either ASCII letters (`A-Za-z`), digits (`0-9`) or whitespace (`\s`)
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SzlsPA/1).

There are some good hints about [*Form Validation in Flutter* here](https://medium.com/@nitishk72/form-validation-in-flutter-d762fbc9212c).

Comment: what does `\s` mean?

Comment: @rozerro `\s` matches any whitespace